# Run xlock after coming back from pm-suspend

Tags: linux, suspend, slackware, xlock

I'm using Slackware 13 on my notebook, and I'm using pm-suspend to have a faster boot up. I'd like to have it run xlock after bringing it back from suspend, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try placing an executable script in `/etc/acpi/resume.d`: `91-xlock.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=":0" su -c your-user-name xlock
```

Also, you can try creating a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` that will create xlock-launcher that executes once, at boot.
Cheers!

Comment: Careful, that script will probably run as root, which means xlock will run as root as well (meaning you need the root password to unlock).

Comment: What can I do to have it run as user?

Comment: I've edited my responce so now it meets Health's remark :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try a script like this that you call for suspend:

```
#!/bin/sh  
xlock&  
sleep 3  
sudo pm-suspend
```